# Show that there is no positive real number which is less than every positive real number.

Tags: logic, real-numbers

I think what would happen if there is less than every positive real numbers
How can I prove that?

Comment: 1. Suppose there is a positive real number that is less than every other positive real number.  Call it “$y$”.
2. Something goes wrong. What might go wrong?

Comment: Ad absurdum. Imagine that number exists and name it $x$. What can you say about $x/2$ ?

Comment: What is more interesting to talk about is the possibility of a number (not a real number itself) that is greater than 0 and less than every positive real number. This gets you nonarchimedean fields such as the hyperreals.

Comment: @BenCrowell Or the set of rational functions in one variable, ordered by which is larger towards infinity.

Comment: @Arthur: Your example is nonarchimedean field.

Comment: @BenCrowell Did I ever say it wasn't? You gave one example, I gave another.

Answer (score 17):

If $0 < \epsilon \in \Bbb R$, and $\epsilon < r$ for every positive $r \in \Bbb R$, then

$\epsilon < \epsilon; \tag 1$

that will obviously not work!

Even if we relax the condition from $\epsilon < r$ to $\epsilon \le r$ for all positive $r \in \Bbb R$, it still won't work, since

$0 < \dfrac{\epsilon}{2} < \epsilon. \tag 2$

Comment: R/2 < R is indeed the correct way to do it.

Comment: @Joshua:  I think so . . . it gets done with things very expeditiously, no?

Comment: Correct, though you still need to establish the fact that ϵ/2∈R (a bit pedantic, but without it, you could use this proof to "prove" that there's no positive *natural* number which is smaller than every other positive natural number - just replace R with N...)

Comment: @G0BLiN More importantly, you have to show that $\epsilon/2$ is strictly smaller than $\epsilon$ and that there isn't some infinitesimally small real number which when divided by $2$ stays the same. If you're not willing to just assume as intuitively obvious that there's no smallest real, why assume any of that?

Comment: @jackm you are correct, all of these "intuitively obvious" details need to be addressed. It all depends on the scope of the proof - if it is already established that R is closed for division, my comment above is addressed, if it is already established that for any x>1 and any positive y, x×y>y, than your point about (epsilon/2)<(epsilon) is covered, etc etc. At any rate, a formal proof about a basic quality of R shouldn't dismiss something as intuitively obvious...

Answer (score 10):

Suppose that there does exist some real $y > 0$ that is less than every other positive real number. Then $y < \frac{1}{n}$ for every natural number $n$. This would then imply that $n < \frac{1}{y}$ for every natural number (the natural numbers would then have an upper bound!) and so we have a contradiction.

Answer (score 4):

If $x$ is a real number then $x/2$ is also a real number $<  x$ with a contradiction.

If the real numbers are made up of the classes of limits of converging Cauchy series then there is a series
$a_1, a_2, a_3, …$ with the limit  $x$

$x/2$  is a real number since there is a Cauchy sequence 
 $a_1/2, a_2/2, a_3/2 , …$ which has the limit  $x/2$

Answer (score 2):

Let $r$ be a positive real. Consider the set $S=\{x\in\mathbb{R}~:~x<r\}$. Now this set $S$ is non-empty, as $0\in S$. So it has a lowest upper bound, say $r^*$. $r^*\leq r$ as $r\not<r$. If $r^*<r$, then $r^*<\frac{r+r^*}{2}<r$. Hence $\frac{r+r^*}{2}\in S$, which contradicts our assumption that $r^*$ is the lowest upper bound. So $r^*=r$, but $r\not\in S$.

Answer (score 2):

Wait, so this number you're looking for would be less than *every* positive real number including *itself*? That's impossible. I think you meant to ask

> Show that there is no positive real number which is less than all *other* positive real numbers.

That's the question the other answerers have already addressed, and which I will now address from a slightly different angle.

Consider the number $$0.000000000000000000000000000000000001.$$ That's a very small number, right? It's definitely smaller than all the positive integers. Well, $$0.0000000000000000000000000000000000001$$ is smaller still. And $$0.00000000000000000000000000000000000001$$ is smaller still. And $$0.000000000000000000000000000000000000001$$ and $$0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000001$$ and $$0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000001$$ and $$0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000001$$ and 
$$0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000001 \ldots$$

Theoretically I can do this all day, but in practice I would exhaust your patience pretty quickly if I haven't already.

Comment: Cute, if not entirely rigorous.  You might consider scientific notation, i.e. the sequence $10^{-n}$ for $n \in \Bbb N$.

Comment: Many students, when presented with this argument, will propose the "number" $$0.00000\dots{}1$$ where the 1 "comes after infinitely many 0s".    Then you have to have a longer discussion about the definition of real numbers, the meaning of decimal expansions, and what a "sequence of digits" really is.  (Incidentally, these same students will claim that $1 \ne 0.9999\dots$ and the number above is what you get when you subtract $0.9999\dots$ from $1$.)